# Refreshing and updating datagridview after query is executed

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to refresh and update 3 datagridviews (a many-to many relationship) when an executed query affects > 0 rows.

`TabsGridsDict` is a  `Dictionary<string,datagridview>` containing the table names and the gridviews.

I have tried this .

```
int rowsAff = DBops.exec_query(query.built);

if (rowsAff > 0)
{
    TabsGridsDict[tableName].Update();
    TabsGridsDict[tableName].Refresh();
}
```

I have also tried to rebind the datagridviews but..it seems it just won't update. It updates after I close the app and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the values database again instead of reading it from TabsGridDict[tableName]

```
int rowsAff = DBops.exec_query(query.built);

if (rowsAff > 0)
{
    // Get the latest values from database and bind it again.    
}
```

Comment: I have tried :                                                                      SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM meal",DBops.constr);
                         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        ada.Fill(dt);

                        TabsGridsDict[tableName].DataSource = dt;

Comment: `if (rowsAff > 0)
{
     SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM meal",DBops.constr); DataTable dt = new DataTable(); ada.Fill(dt); TabsGridsDict[tableName].DataSource = dt;
}` Can you check that, is that works for you?

Comment: The datasource of the datagridview contains the datatable but still it wont appear on the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using sqldataadapter ,filling a table and assigning the datasource of the datagridview with the table.